# Problema con mux: localhost devuelve un 404

Tags: backend, go

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo basico del patron de diseño ''repository''. Este es mi router (mux)

```
    func StartRouter() {

    //port := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", "3000")
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

    fmt.Println("Starting...")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router))

    //r := app.CreateRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/healthcheck", common.HealthCheck).Methods("GET")

    archetypeRepository := repository.NewArchetypeRepository()
    archetypeService := service.NewArchetypeService(archetypeRepository)
    archetypeController := controller.NewArchetypeController(archetypeService)

    router.HandleFunc("/", archetypeController.ArchetypeControllerExample).Methods("GET")

}
```

y la función que maneja el index es:

```
    func (controller *ArchetypeController) ArchetypeControllerExample(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    >//Este print era para ver si se ejecuta pero no se imprime
    fmt.Println("here is")
    statusCode, responseBody := controller.Service.ArchetypeServiceExample()

    if statusCode != nil {
        log.Fatal(statusCode)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseBody)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

Donde statusCode recibe un error.
Al ejecutar esto me imprime `404 page not found` en `localhost:3000` y desde la consola; `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Ya he trabajado con varios endpoints antes y es la primera vez que me pasa esto.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el issue...

```
func StartRouter() {

//port := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", "3000")
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

fmt.Println("Starting...")

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router))

//r := app.CreateRouter()

router.HandleFunc("/healthcheck", common.HealthCheck).Methods("GET")

archetypeRepository := repository.NewArchetypeRepository()
archetypeService := service.NewArchetypeService(archetypeRepository)
archetypeController := controller.NewArchetypeController(archetypeService)

router.HandleFunc("/", archetypeController.ArchetypeControllerExample).Methods("GET")
```

}

Al hacer log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)) antes de declarar las rutas basicamente estaba levantando un servidor vacío, lo que retorna un 404.
Asique la solución fue mas simple de lo que pensé...

```
func StartRouter() {

//port := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", "3000")
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

fmt.Println("Starting...")



//r := app.CreateRouter()

router.HandleFunc("/healthcheck", common.HealthCheck).Methods("GET")

archetypeRepository := repository.NewArchetypeRepository()
archetypeService := service.NewArchetypeService(archetypeRepository)
archetypeController := controller.NewArchetypeController(archetypeService)

router.HandleFunc("/", archetypeController.ArchetypeControllerExample).Methods("GET")

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router))
```

}

> Con tan solo declarar log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)) se arregla el problema.